# Proper way to return error from within a mutateAndGetPayload

Tags: relayjs, relay

I am doing a number of business logic checks within the mutateAndGetPayload function of a relay mutation using the graphql-relay library. For any of these checks that fail I have an else clause that will throw an error, ig `throw('You do not have permission to delete this resource');`, however, when that happens, I get the error `Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined` returned to the frontend instead of the error I'm trying to return. It seems that I'm seeing this error because I'm not returning something this mutation cares about (or a promise that resolves to one), so I'm a little stumped ... what's the proper way to throw/return errors back to the client here?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the GraphQLError Type

Working in NodeJS on the back end we have used the following library:

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/tree/master/src/error

However, what we have ended up using is a library that provides more flexibility:

https://github.com/kadirahq/graphql-errors

Either of these would be the best place to start.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.